# jQuery Validate Plugin get more control

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can I get more control or error placement? I have similar error messages for two elements and I want only one of them to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can control error placement using the following options

```
errorElement
errorLabelContainer
errorContainer
```

View Docs Here http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

These docs have demos and example code.. Its very helpful.