# how to customize the position of the error message for each field from jquery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jquery validate plugin, in combination with some custom field types (custom select boxes)

default behaviour of the jquery validation plugin is to insert the error message element, right after the form element.
though that would render the error message inbetween the hidden select element, and the replaced ul element for custom select box functionality.

i found the option: 'errorLabelContainer but that places all errors in that 1 container.

I am looking for a solution to place the error label below every form element, (and so, after the custom form elements like these fake select boxes), and not the custuom position option that places all errors in the same container.

if this would involve moving them manually after each error trigger,
i'd rather have a clean solution first

Comment: very simular to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908806/jquery-validate-plugin-get-more-control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`errorPlacement`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) option for this, for example:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.insertAfter(element.parent());
   }
});
```

I'm not sure what "below" means in your code, but this is undoubtedly the option your after, it's called for each element, and you can replace the error in relation to the element however you want.  The *default* for this option is `error.insertAfter(element);`, making it appear just after the element.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i'm looking for, below can mean anything i can change the html around so it will not be insert after parent, but it will be more like appendTo(parent) as its the last element in the LI i can use css clear properties to make it show below the item.  thanks alot for this!